# how to save multipartformdatacontent in memory with memorystream in C# xamarin forms android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to save a MultipartFormDataContent in memory and then read it using MemoryStream.

I'm trying to do it with this code in Xamarin forms:

```
MultipartFormDataContent content2 = new MultipartFormDataContent();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
```

in my code I have this to write in MemoryStream:

```
await content2.CopyToAsync(ms);
```

I don't know how to read it and convert it in a MultipartFormDataContent.

So basically my question is:

1. How could I save and read it with MemoryStream and convert what I read in MultipartFormDataContent?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `MultipartFormDataContent content2 = new MultipartFormDataContent();` - `content2` is a reference to the object you created in memory.  You don't need to use `MemoryStream`

Comment: but when the user power off the aplication I don't have that  saved in memory.

Comment: if the app is killed or the device is shut down, NOTHING is retained in memory.  Your question is specifically asking about saving **in memory**.   If you want it persisted then you need to save it to a file or in a db